# FreeIPA external CA (intermediate CA)

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, ca

we're doing a freeipa install using our existing CA. During the install, a CSR is generated and must be signed by the CA to create a certificate. This certificate must have

> X509v3 Basic Constraints:
>                   CA:TRUE

I have been researching for about an hour now and I'm at a loss of what to do.  Typically, i sign CSR's as such

```
openssl x509 -req -in ipa.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out ipa.pem
```

this works but CA:TRUE isn't there.
i tried doing this:

```
openssl x509 -req -in ipa.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -extensions v3_ca -out ipa.pem
```

and it generated the same capabilities as the original.

I can see that the generated key pulls info from my openssl.cnf, but it's ignoring the extensions statement, which is below.

```
[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = CA:true
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what i need to do, or what additional information i can provide?  thanks!

Sidenote: I have no gui or gui tools, this is all from the command line. The CSR is generated by the IPA software, i am not creating it manually.

here's the note from IPA:

> The CA signing certificate generated for the Identity Management
>   server must be a valid CA certificate. This requires either that the
>   Basic Constraint be set to CA=true or that the Key Usage Extension be
>   set on the signing certificate to allow it to sign certificates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make openssl x509 read a specific config using the "-extfile" command.

I would suggest you make a new config, lets name it foo.cnf.
Inside it put:

```
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
basicConstraints = CA:true
```

Now run your command with a small change:

```
openssl x509 -req -in ipa.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -extfile foo.cnf -out ipa.pem
```

You should now have a cert with CA:true.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create config file first

   tee ca.cnf <<EOF
   [ v3_ca ]
   subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
   authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always
   basicConstraints = CA:true
   EOF
2. Use it when signing with option

> -extensions v3_ca -extfile ca.cnf

```
sudo openssl x509 -req -in ipa.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -extensions v3_ca -extfile ca.cnf -out ipa.crt
```

3. Check

   sudo openssl x509 -text -noout -in ipa.crt